# Why am I getting a syntax error with a SQL clause provided by Google's Data Analytics team

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For the Hands On Activity: Applying SQL} I am instructed to write a query to determine how many total lightning strikes happen in 2018.

here is the query I used to extract the total lightning strikes in 2018:

```
SELECT SUM(number_of_strikes) 
FROM 'bigquery-public-data.noaa_lightning.lightning_2018' 
LIMIT 1000
```

I don't understand why I am getting an syntax error ?

Comment: Add the error you are getting to your question (using [Edit]).

Comment: you should use back-ticks instead of apostrophes!

Answer (score 0):

###### From

```
'bigquery-public-data.noaa_lightning.lightning_2018'
```

→ Error Message: Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'bigquery-public-data.noaa_lightning.lightning_2018' at [2:6]

###### To

```
`bigquery-public-data.noaa_lightning.lightning_2018`
```

Use `backtick` `` (`) `` instead of a single quote `(')`. The detailed information can be found in [BQ Tables Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables).